# SDK Parse.com for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-10

I would like to build an application for universal application Windows 10 with Parse.com. But I only see SDK Parse.com for Windows and Windows phone v1.6. Please help me choose which SDK to build universal application Windows 10. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 (on desktop and phones) uses WinRT, just like Windows 8 did. So if you install the v1.6 of the SDK for Windows, it should work since it's targeting Windows 8.

Overall, I recommend you to add the Parse SDK to your application directly from Visual Studio [by using NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/parse). This way, you'll be absolutely sure to use a compatible version.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TienLongTran Don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your issue ;)